# Need Help as to how I am getting a different Output

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am trying to implement the Bubble Sort Algorithm in C++ but I am not getting the desired output which I require, so I need help regarding that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void BubbleSort(int arr[] , int n)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<n-1 ; i++) // Iterating for (n-1) Rounds 
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
            {
                int temp ; 
                temp=arr[j]; 
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp ; 
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,arr[50] ; 
    cin >> n ; 

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i]; 
    }

    BubbleSort(arr,n);

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " " ; 
    }
}
```

Sample Test Case (with Size 7): `2 13 4 1 3 6 28`
Expected Output: `1 2 3 4 6 13 28`
Actual Output (that I am getting): `1 0 2 3 4 6 13`

Comment: There is at least 1 bug here: `if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])`

Comment: @drescherjm So , How should i go about resolving that ?

Comment: You want to adjust the loop for `j` because that if statement will access `arr[n]` when `j == n-1`

Comment: @drescherjm Please tell me the exact modifications which needs to be done in my code so that i can have a better understanding ?

Comment: is this really bubblesort (sorry I dont recognize it ;). This looks like O(n^2) while bubblesort should be O(n), no?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 There is no (comparison based) O(n) sorting algorithm. Bubblesort is O(n^2).

Comment: There is an answer here that fixes the problem with your `for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: @melpomene I misunderstood what I read on wikipedia, it says best case complexity is linear, which can be achieved with small modifications on OPs code I think

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
{
    if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
    {
        int temp ; 
        temp=arr[j]; 
        arr[j]=arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1]=temp ; 
    }

}
```

there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array when `j` is equal to `n - 1` because in this case `j + 1` gives `n` and the array does not have an element at the index equal to `n`. So this expression `arr[j+1]` in this case is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Change the inner loop to `for(int j=0 ; j<n-i-1 ; j++)`. Every time an inner loop gets completely executed, an element will be in correct position. That means, inner loop should executes `n-i-1` times.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ; 

void BubbleSort(int arr[] , int n)
{

    for(int i=0 ; i<n-1 ; i++) // Iterating for (n-1) Rounds 
{

    for(int j=0 ; j<n-i-1 ; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
        {
            int temp ; 
            temp=arr[j]; 
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=temp ; 
        }

    }
}

}

int main(){
    int n,arr[50] ; 
    cin >> n ; 

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i]; 
    }

    BubbleSort(arr,n);

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " " ; 
    }
}
```

In bubble sort, one complete execution of the inner loop will put the largest element of the array into the bottom of the array. After the first execution of the inner loop, the largest element will be in the nth position or last position. So during the second execution, inner loop should parse only `n-1` elements and copies the second largest element to `n-1` th position or second last position. Similarly, it goes for `n-2`,`n-3` ... till the first element i.e `n-i`. Hence `j<n-i-1`

To put it simply, it sorts from the bottom to top (upward direction) like the bubbles.